# Firebase.database( ) object has no 'ref' method or 'Reference' method to call

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, web

I have started with firebase , but have run into an annoying problem for a while. When ever I create a `database` object with `firebase.database()` , when I try to call the `ref` method ,  there is no ref method available. I am using WEBSTORM IDE from JetBrains. So when i push the data , it won't go into the database. Here is my code .
The script below is named main.js .

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
function loginclicked()
{

    var database = firebase.database()

    var ref = database.ref('Scores') ;

    var data = {"Name" :"Natesh" , "Age" : 27} ;

    ref.push(data) ;
```

}

Here is my data in the database :-

[image]

My project name is 'sit-notifier' , I have also set the database rules to accept all requests.

**EDIT1 : -**
I found that the firebase object itself is not getting initialised for some reason . That is why the `database` object won't be created and hence the ref .

Here is my index.html code which calls the above java script code :-

```
    <body class="center">

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->


        <h1 class="mainheading">Notification Generator</h1>


        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase.js"></script>

        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-database.js"></script>


        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-Y to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            window.ga=function(){ga.q.push(arguments)};ga.q=[];ga.l=+new Date;
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-Y','auto');ga('send','pageview')
        </script>
        <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "when I try to call the ref method , there is no ref method available". you get an error invoking it? What does the `firebase.database()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was in the order i called the `main.js` script in the index.html file. Once I fixed it , it works like charm.

Here is the fixed code :-

```
<body class="center">

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>



        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>



        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-Y to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            window.ga=function(){ga.q.push(arguments)};ga.q=[];ga.l=+new Date;
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-Y','auto');ga('send','pageview')
        </script>
        <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
```